# "He won't (likely) be... so much... as for..." How can I paraphrase it?

Tags: adverbs, comparative-constructions, would-rather

> He **won't** likely be remembered **so much** for his accomplishments **as for** his character.

Is this sentence similar to the following?

> He **will** be remembered for his character **rather than** for his accomplishments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two sentences are largely the same in meaning.

To make the second sentence even closer to the first you could say

> He will be remembered for his character **more so** than for his accomplishments.

which matches more closely with the implication of the first sentence that he may be remembered *a little bit* for his accomplishments but *mostly* for his character.

Answer (score 0):

Your two sentences:

> He won't likely be remembered so much for his accomplishments as for his character.
>
> He will be remembered for his character rather than for his accomplishments.

In the first sentence there is 'as for', it means **considering or speaking about** according to http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-for you can also think it as **with regard to or concerning** according to http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20for . In the second sentence there is **rather than**. We use it to give more importance to one thing when two alternatives or preferences are being compared. Rather than usually occurs between two things being compared. For more information, check- http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/rather

All things considered, Your first sentence isn't like second sentence. They conveys two different meanings as follows:

> **1st sentence could mean** :-Considering/speaking about his character,
>   he won't likely be remembered so much for his accomplishments.
>   It says that his character isn good enough. May be his character has affected his accomplishment.

---

> **2nd sentence could mean** : He will be remembered for his character compared to his accomplishments.
>   It says that his character is better than his accomplishment, so he will be remembered for his character.